# Cannot update VMware Tools in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, vmware-player

I have a Windows XP Pro virtual machine installed in VMware player 15. I have had some trouble installing VMware tools on the XP-station. When I tried to do it manually with the latest ISO-file, I got the error message that it's `not a valid Win32-program`. After some fiddling I downloaded an ISO-file with version 9.4.15 and got it to work.

Now it seems I have to update VMware tools to a enable accelerated 3d graphics and I'm at a loss here. The option to `Update VMware tools...` is greyed out and I can't find any ISO-files that will run direct in the guest system. I still get the error message that it's not a valid program.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of VNware Tools in a Windows XP guest is V10.0.12 so your version is pretty close. In the Player Menu, look at your tabs and the VM tab will have Reinstall VMware tools (I am going from Workstation). See if you can reinstall the Tools. You cannot go past V10 because XP is out of support everywhere and VMware stopped Tool version for XP at V10.

Comment: Couldn't find anything that said Reinstall VMware Tools. Nevertheless, downloading 10.0.9 ISO-file seem to have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. My Windows XP Guest originates from  time when XP was supported.